# How to make the folder text bigger on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Description]

I change the code font size but I couldn't make folder text bigger on VS Code as you see. Is there anyone to know how to change folder text?

Comment: it is a dirty hack but you can change the style sheet used by VSC for the workbench. Change style `.monaco-workbench .part>.content` this controls the whole side bar font size `workbench.desktop.main.css` somewhere in the resources subdir

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or on Mac <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

That will zoom the GUI like in a browser

Comment: Thanks your answer but I want to make bigger only folder text without code text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that is a compromise but maybe it will appeal to you: **Set the editor text to be smaller, then "zoom in" like in a browser until the browser is how you want it.**

I use the opposite because I want the tabs to be smaller, and I didn't find a way to control the size of them.

Basically you have two controls: Code size and overall zoom level. So what you can play around with is changing the code size bigger or smaller, then re-zooming to find the balance that makes sense for you.

The downside to this answer is that ALL of the UI outside the code itself will be affected, not just the file explorer, so you'll end up with big tabs, big git, big command palette etc.

I really with VS Code offered more font size options! I'm dying for a way to control the different parts in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change the text size in the editor or in the menus is to go to your Keyboard shortcuts.

Type in zoom

```
View: Zoom in: Command + Shift + =
View: Zoom out: Command + Shift + -
Editor Font Zoom In: Command + =
Editor Font Zoom Out: Command + -
```

[image]

Now you can adjust your editor size and / or your folder size.